# Is this property of continuous maps equivalent to some more familiar condition?

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness, locales

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. Suppose that, for each collection of open sets $\{ V_i \}_{i \in I}\subset X $,

$$ \bigcup_{U \subset Y \text{ open}, \ f^{-1}(U) \subset \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i } U = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{U \subset Y \text{ open},\ f^{-1}(U) \subset V_i} U. \tag{1}\label{1}$$

I wonder whether this property is equivalent to being proper for locally compact hausdorff spaces. Below I have a proof of one direction.

Write $f^*(V) = \bigcup_{f^{-1}(U) \subset V} U$. \eqref{1} says that $f^*$ preserves joins, so that it has a right adjoint $f^!$. Is $f^!$ related to some kind of compact support condition?

If this situation works like sheaves on compact hausdorff spaces, then proper should imply this condition. Maybe they are even equivalent?

**Proposition:** A proper map $f$ satisfies \eqref{1}.

**Proof:** Suppose $f$ is proper. Then, for any $C \subset Y$ compact, $X \times_Y C$ is compact. So, for any filtered collection of opens $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ in $X \times_Y C$ with union $X \times_Y C$, there is $i_0 \in I$ with $U_i = X \times_Y C$, so that $f_*(\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i) = f_*( U_{i_0}) = \bigcup_{i \in I} f_*(U_i)$.

Suppose $f$ is proper. Let $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of opens in $X$. Then $\bigcup_{i \in I} f^*( U_i )$ contains all compact subsets contained in $f^*(\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i)$. Since points are compact, proper implies \eqref{1}.

**Proposition:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally compact hausdorff spaces and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. Then $f$ is proper if and only if it is closed and the preimage of points is compact.

So we just need to show that $f$ is closed if it satisfies \eqref{1}. Edit: it looks like this is known. Consider the adjoint to intersection with an open set $U \subset X$, $W \mapsto [U, W] := \text{sup}_{V \cap U \subset W} V$. It is known that $f^*([U, W]) = [f^*(U), f^*(W)]$. But $f^*$ preserves suprema, so this is true.

It looks like this is true, but perhaps in a more general context? Any insights here are valuable to me.

Comment: Your proposition is false: let $f:\{0,1\}\to\{0\}$ be the obvious map ($\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology). Let $V_i=\{i\}$ ($i=0,1$); then $f^*(V_i)=\emptyset$. So the right-hand side in (1) is empty and the left-hand side in $\{0\}$.

Comment: @KPHart Thanks, I deleted it.

Comment: Your second proposition seems false: take $Y$ to be a point and $X$ not compact. Your condition reminds of "Tube lemma".

Comment: Sorry, I meant compact instead of closed